# Call Html.Actionlink from script

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I am trying to call action link from script but it is not working,
but when I am using `window.open` it is working but I need other properties because of my CSS view, if I can call `Html.ActionLink` I can open it in tabs at the same page with my template.

Here is code:

```
 function OnRowDblClick(s, e) {
    alert(e.visibleIndex);
    GridViewCitiesList.GetRowValues(e.visibleIndex, "CityGuid", OnGetRowValues);
}

function OnGetRowValues(data) {
    var url = Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CityAction", "City", new { CRUDType: CRUDTypes.Update, ModelGuid: data }, new { class: "btn btn-success", target: "_blank", title: "City Detail" });
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Error says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Html is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues with current code:

1) `Html.ActionLink` is an MVC helper, you should add `@` prefix in Razor CSHTML page to set it as HTML helper.

2) `Html.ActionLink` generates anchor tag (`<a>`), not URL string. Use [`@Url.Action()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd492874(v=vs.118)) helper to create URL.

3) `data` is client-side variable, you can't pass it to HTML helper which processed server-side. You need to build query string to add `data` with `ModelGuid` parameter.

Based from explanations above, change URL definition from this:

```
// this is totally wrong
var url = Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CityAction", "City", new { CRUDType: CRUDTypes.Update, ModelGuid: data }, new { class: "btn btn-success", target: "_blank", title: "City Detail" });
```

to this one:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("CityAction", "City", new { CRUDType = CRUDTypes.Update })&ModelGuid=' + data;
```

Or you may try adding `ModelGuid` parameter query string inside `routeValues` and replace its value from client-side:

```
// this setup should also work
function OnGetRowValues(data) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("CityAction", "City", new { CRUDType = CRUDTypes.Update, ModelGuid = "XXXX" })';
    url = url.replace('XXXX', data);

    window.location.href = url;
}
```